# Finding sum of selected in flot

Tags: jquery, user-interface, graph, flot

If I bind a function to flot's "plotselected" event, is there a way to get the main series indexes of the start and end points of the selected area?

I saw that with "plothover" you can use the "item" variable, but it's not clear if that works for selections. Plus, I don't want to have to iterate through the entire series each time the function is called. My goal is get something like:

```
 $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (itemx1, itemx2) {
          var x1 = itemx1.plot.pos //The index for this plot point in series";
          var x2 = itemx2.plot.pos //The index for this plot point in series";
          var sum = 0;
          for (var i = x1; i < x2; i++) {
               sum += d[i][0];
               }
          $("#total_selected").text(sum);
          });
```

If I could get that, I could also output (with my data) something like:

```
         "You earned X points over Y days, Z hours, F minutes. Good Job!"
```

Seems like this should be simple, but flot is really throwing me for a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: did you mean to write:

    var x2 = itemx2.plot.pos //The index for this plot point in series";

Comment: Yes! good eye. I've fixed it. I want the sum of the area selected. I  wish that flot had some basic  Riemann sum type action where I could get a more accurate sum at any two points. Shouldn't be hard, since my lines don't curve, but that's what I get for stopping at Algebra 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [flot api documentation](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt): the "plotselected" event function takes two paremeters "event" and "ranges". The ranges object contains the x and y coordinates of the selection.

```
$('#placeholder').bind('plotselected', function (event, ranges) {
  var x1 = ranges.xaxis.from;
  var x2 = ranges.xaxis.to;
  var y1 = ranges.yaxis.from;
  var y2 = ranges.yaxis.to;       
  var sum = 0;

  /* The values returned by the coordinates are floats. 
     You may need to tweak this to get the correct results.*/
  for (var i = x1; i < x2; i++) {
       sum += d[i][0];
  }
  $("#total_selected").text(sum);
});
```

Comment: Except that the documentation you linked to doesn't mention "plotselected" at all.